# How to properly pull an apk using adb and subprocess in python

Tags: python, android, subprocess, adb

I'm trying to get apks based on the number it falls on on the select menu but I can't seem to get apk path when I enter it's number on the selection menu using adb and subprocess I aim to use apktool to decompile it when it's done but this is what I get when I enter the number on the select menu.

```
/system/bin/sh: <stdin>[1]: 15: inaccessible or not found
```

I read the docs and followed it closely below here is my code what am I doing wrong?
I would love to know.

```
#  Create a select menu of all the available packages on the emulator and let the user choose one
output = subprocess.run(["adb", "-s", device_id, "shell", "pm", "list", "packages", "-3"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode("utf-8")
packages = output.strip().split("\n")
print("Available packages:")
for i, package in enumerate(packages):
    print(f"{i+1}: {package}")
package_index = int(input("Enter the number of the package to extract: ")) - 1
print(package_index)

# Print the path of the selected package and extract it to the local filesystem
package = packages[package_index]
print(package)
##print(packages)
package_name = package.split(":")[1]
print(package_name)
new_output = subprocess.run(["adb","-s", device_id, "shell", "pm", "path", package_name], capture_output=True).stdout.decode("utf-8")
package_path = new_output.strip().split(":")[1]
#print(output)
#print(package_path)

#print(f"Full path of {package_name}: {package_path}")
apk_type = input("Enter 1 to extract a single APK file, or 2 to extract a split APK: ")
if apk_type == "1":
    print("Hhhhh")
    #subprocess.run(["adb" ,"-s", device_id, "pull", package_path, f"{package_name}.apk"])
else:
    print("Working in progress......................................")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `adb shell pm path packageId` instead. So from

```
new_output = subprocess.run(["adb","-s", device_id, "shell", "pm grant", "path", package_name], capture_output=True).stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

to

```
new_output = subprocess.run(["adb","-s", device_id, "shell", "pm", "path", package_name], capture_output=True).stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

after this change your python script will work.

Below the updated script, running against an emulator (tested with Python3.8.12, MacOS):

```
import subprocess
device_id="emulator-5554"

#  Create a select menu of all the available packages on the emulator and let the user choose one
output = subprocess.run(["adb", "-s", device_id, "shell", "pm", "list", "packages", "-3"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode("utf-8")
packages = output.strip().split("\n")
print("Available packages:")
for i, package in enumerate(packages):
    print(f"{i+1}: {package}")
package_index = int(input("Enter the number of the package to extract: ")) - 1
print(package_index)

# Print the path of the selected package and extract it to the local filesystem
package = packages[package_index]
print(package)
##print(packages)
package_name = package.split(":")[1]
print(package_name)
new_output = subprocess.run(["adb","-s", device_id, "shell", "pm", "path", package_name], capture_output=True).stdout.decode("utf-8")
package_path = new_output.strip().split(":")[1]
#print(output)
#print(package_path)

#print(f"Full path of {package_name}: {package_path}")
apk_type = input("Enter 1 to extract a single APK file, or 2 to extract a split APK: ")
if apk_type == "1":
    print("Hhhhh")
    subprocess.run(["adb" ,"-s", device_id, "pull", package_path, f"{package_name}.apk"])
else:
    print("Working in progress......................................")
```

Comment: Hi @Lino I just made the change and it's still giving the same results

Comment: updated the script I used to make it work. I'm able to download the apk successfully.

Comment: When I enter a number for an apk it does not print it's path it keeps displaying the error message

Comment: I'm using python Python 3.10.10 @Lino does that have any effect should it not be the same result

Comment: tried also with python 3.10 and it works

Comment: It is not printing the path on my end and trying to pull the apk results in 
 ```
adb: error: failed to stat remote object '': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pull apk file `/data/app/xxx/xx.apk` directly, try copy it to some 'normal' path:

```
adb shell "cp /data/app/xxx/base.apk /sdcard/"
adb pull /sdcard/base.apk ./package_name.apk
```